# Relationship Between Tangent, Cotangent, and Modulo

Tags: trigonometry

Would appreciate any feedback or prof of the following equation:

$\tan\left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x,\pi\right)-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)=-\cot\left(x\right)$

$mod(x,\pi)$=x modulo $(\pi)$

Comment: Tan has period $\pi$; tan and cot are co-functions

Comment: @J.W. Tamer: It will be most appreciated if you can you expand on the relationship of co-function and modulo?

Answer (score 0):

The equation follows from some well-known properties of the tangent

(and its reciprocal, the cotangent) function:

(a)  it has period $\pi$; that means $\tan(x+n\pi)=\tan(x)$, where $n$ is any integer;

(b)  it is odd; that means $\tan(-x)=-\tan(x)$; and

(c)  tangent and cotangent are [cofunctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofunction); that means $\tan\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)=\cot(x)$.